# How to call the storyboard action from codebehind?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I'm new to Silverlight. I've got a animation for flip form the net and I followed the same step. It works fine for me and am trying to implement that from the codebehind. How can I do this?

```
xmlns:TransitionBehaviours="clr-namespace:RMGUtils.RT.UI.Helpers.ShowHideTransition"

 <Grid x:Name="DataGridBack">

     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
             <TransitionBehaviours:ShowHideWithFlip  ShowElementName="FrontFaceGrid" HideElementName="AlternateFaceGrid" Direction="BottomToTopCrazy" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>

 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a [story board](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/animation-and-easing/animations-%28silverlight-quickstart%29) from code behind as follows

```
mystoryboard.Begin();
```

Comment: the ShowHideWithFlip is a class file and in that,the code has a begin() inside as a last line

Comment: FYI i got the sample file from http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/ShowHideWithFlip

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing here is not really a storyboard but a trigger. The whole point of having a trigger is you don't need to write any code behind to call it. You can attach it to any controls, for example you can attach it to a button and set the EventName to Click.

Comment: Thanks,But when am trying to use this inside the datagrid with a button in a column for that it is not working

Comment: The button inside the dg is one level down, so the ShowElementName and AlternateFaceGrid won't work as they can't find the Grids by their names, you need to change the code in the trigger to get this to work, or you can try putting it outside of the dg.